# About intersections of two totally isotropic subspaces fo a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q$ be a quadratic form on $\mathbb R^{2m}$ with the signature $(m,m)$. The maximal totally isotropic subspaces  in $(\mathbb R^{2m},Q)$ have then dimensions $m$.

What dimensions $1,...,m-1$ of intersections of two m.t.i. subspaces are realized?

Comment: All of them, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Take a hyperbolic basis $e_1,\ldots,e_m,f_1,\ldots,f_m$ such that $(e_i,e_j)=0$, $(f_i,f_j)=0$ and $(e_i,f_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Then the isotropic subspaces $\langle e_1,\ldots,e_k,f_{k+1},\ldots,f_m\rangle$ and $\langle e_1,\ldots,e_m \rangle$ meet at the subspace of dimension $k$, $k=0,\ldots,m$.